# Calculating an x week average from Crosstab

Tags: python, pandas

I have a crosstab table with scores for different user IDs for each week. Each row is a different user ID and each column is the week end date. It looks something like this:

```
      01/01/2020   07/01/2020   14/01/2020    21/01/2020   28/01/2020          
1     0.8          0.8          0.95          0.66         0.9
2     0.9          0.6          0.55          0.56         0.88
3     1.0          0.4          0.66          null          0.67
4     0.5          0.2          null          0.8          0.45
```

I would like to replace **every cell in the table** with the average of the score and the previous two scores (the actual dataframe is very large with several months of data). For example instead of 0.9 in the top right it would be (0.9 + 0.66 + 0.95) / 3 = 0.836667. Sometimes there will null values in the cells, in which case I would like to divide by the number of non-null cells (i.e. for the bottom right it would be (0.45 + 0.8) / 2). I can the average per row but have not been able to specify the average of the cells. Any help would be really appreciated.

This is the data:

```
{'2020-08-14': {100000151529577: nan, 100000168029563: 0.9523809523809521},
 '2020-08-21': {100000151529577: nan, 100000168029563: 0.6666666666666661},
 '2020-09-04': {100000151529577: 0.8444444444444441, 100000168029563: nan},
 '2020-09-11': {100000151529577: 0.877551020408163, 100000168029563: 1.0},
 '2020-09-18': {100000151529577: 0.7884615384615381,
  100000168029563: 0.9047619047619041},
 '2020-09-25': {100000151529577: 0.9487179487179481, 100000168029563: 0.9},
 '2020-10-02': {100000151529577: 0.8536585365853651,
  100000168029563: 0.893617021276595},
 '2020-10-09': {100000151529577: 0.9189189189189191,
  100000168029563: 0.9302325581395341},
 '2020-10-16': {100000151529577: 0.8690476190476191,
  100000168029563: 0.904850746268656},
 '2020-10-23': {100000151529577: 0.934537246049661,
  100000168029563: 0.957627118644067},
 '2020-10-30': {100000151529577: 0.972447325769854,
  100000168029563: 0.9822560202788341},
 '2020-11-06': {100000151529577: 0.8617021276595741,
  100000168029563: 0.875912408759124},
 '2020-11-13': {100000151529577: 0.9708737864077671,
  100000168029563: 0.8983050847457621}}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the most compact solution but it takes care of you problem:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d = {'2020-08-14': {100000151529577: np.nan, 100000168029563: 0.9523809523809521},
 '2020-08-21': {100000151529577:  np.nan, 100000168029563: 0.6666666666666661},
 '2020-09-04': {100000151529577: 0.8444444444444441, 100000168029563:  np.nan},
 '2020-09-11': {100000151529577: 0.877551020408163, 100000168029563: 1.0},
 '2020-09-18': {100000151529577: 0.7884615384615381,
  100000168029563: 0.9047619047619041},
 '2020-09-25': {100000151529577: 0.9487179487179481, 100000168029563: 0.9},
 '2020-10-02': {100000151529577: 0.8536585365853651,
  100000168029563: 0.893617021276595},
 '2020-10-09': {100000151529577: 0.9189189189189191,
  100000168029563: 0.9302325581395341},
 '2020-10-16': {100000151529577: 0.8690476190476191,
  100000168029563: 0.904850746268656},
 '2020-10-23': {100000151529577: 0.934537246049661,
  100000168029563: 0.957627118644067},
 '2020-10-30': {100000151529577: 0.972447325769854,
  100000168029563: 0.9822560202788341},
 '2020-11-06': {100000151529577: 0.8617021276595741,
  100000168029563: 0.875912408759124},
 '2020-11-13': {100000151529577: 0.9708737864077671,
  100000168029563: np.nan}}
```

I introduced a `NaN` value in the second rows last entry.

```
df['average'] = df[[ '2020-10-30','2020-11-06','2020-11-13']].mean(axis=1)
df2 = df.drop(['2020-11-13'],axis =1)
df3 = df2.rename(columns={'average': '2020-11-13'})
```

which returns

```
               2020-08-14  2020-08-21  2020-09-04  2020-09-11  2020-09-18  \
100000151529577         NaN         NaN    0.844444    0.877551    0.788462   
100000168029563    0.952381    0.666667         NaN    1.000000    0.904762   

                 2020-09-25  2020-10-02  2020-10-09  2020-10-16  2020-10-23  \
100000151529577    0.948718    0.853659    0.918919    0.869048    0.934537   
100000168029563    0.900000    0.893617    0.930233    0.904851    0.957627   

                 2020-10-30  2020-11-06  2020-11-13  
100000151529577    0.972447    0.861702    0.935008  
100000168029563    0.982256    0.875912    0.929084
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I am actually looking to replace every cell in the df with the average of itself and the previous two cells, apologies for not making this clear. My actual dataframe is very large with several months of data